# Circular dependencies cannot exist in RelativeLayout - why?

Tags: android

I get this error in android : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Circular dependencies cannot exist in RelativeLayout. I think the problem is on XML code. XML codes are in below. But the codes are complex.

XML Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/anasayfab"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/anasayfa"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    />

    <com.example.xxx.xxx.cizim
            android:id="@+id/cizim"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tablo"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/tablo"
    />

    <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tablo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/anasayfab"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/sozcukl1"
    >

        <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tabloa"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tabloaa"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
            />

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tabloab"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
            />

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tabloac"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
            />

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tabload"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
            />

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tabloae"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
            />

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tabloaf"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
            />

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tabloag"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
            />

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tabloah"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
            />

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tabloai"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
            />

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tabloaj"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
            />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tablob"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tabloba"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
            />

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tablobb"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
            />

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tablobc"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
            />

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tablobd"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
            />

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tablobe"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
            />

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tablobf"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
            />

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tablobg"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
            />

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tablobh"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
            />

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tablobi"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
            />

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tablobj"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
            />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tabloc"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tabloca"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
            />

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tablocb"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
            />

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tablocc"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
            />

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tablocd"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
            />

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tabloce"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
            />

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tablocf"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
            />

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tablocg"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
            />

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tabloch"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
            />

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tabloci"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
            />

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tablocj"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
            />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tablod"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tabloda"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
            />

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tablodb"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
            />

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tablodc"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
            />

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tablodd"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
            />

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tablode"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
            />

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tablodf"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
            />

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tablodg"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
            />

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tablodh"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
            />

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tablodi"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
            />

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tablodj"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
            />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tabloe"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tabloea"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
            />

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tabloeb"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
            />

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tabloec"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
            />

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tabloed"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
            />

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tabloee"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
            />

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tabloef"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
            />

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tabloeg"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
            />

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tabloeh"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
            />

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tabloei"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
            />

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tabloej"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
            />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tablof"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tablofa"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
            />

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tablofb"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
            />

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tablofc"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
            />

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tablofd"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
            />

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tablofe"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
            />

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tabloff"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"

            />

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tablofg"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
            />

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tablofh"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
            />

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tablofi"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
            />

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tablofj"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
            />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tablog"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tabloga"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
            />

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tablogb"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
            />

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tablogc"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
            />

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tablogd"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
            />

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tabloge"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
            />

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tablogf"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
            />

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tablogg"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
            />

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tablogh"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
            />

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tablogi"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
            />

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tablogj"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
            />

        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/sozcukl1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tablo"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
    >

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/sozcukta"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/sozcuktb"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/sozcuktc"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/sozcuktd"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/sozcukte"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/sozcukl2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tablo"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/sozcukl1"
            android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
    >

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/sozcuktf"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/sozcuktg"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/sozcukth"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/sozcukti"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/sozcuktj"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I hope you are understand.

How can I resolve this problem?

I need your help.

I wait your responses.

Comment: Here is your layout with everything that wouldn't cause this issue stripped out: https://drive.google.com/file/d/11YOwhxJWWarSTGzJVtUK844mRcpxLb4d/view?usp=drivesdk. Is it easier to spot the problem like that?

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks. I will try.

Comment: @Mike M. Thanks a lot. I resolved.